# Apparently spurious compilation warning

Tags: blackberry

In my main screen class, I get the following warning:

> Warning!: member data 'String url' not
>   required in class:
>   com.mycompany.score.MyScreen
>   [...] line 54

Now, line 54 is:

```
48  public class MyScreen extends MainScreen
49  {
50      private HorizontalFieldManager  editPane;
51      private VerticalFieldManager    buttonPane;
52      private HorizontalFieldManager  contentPane;
53      private LabelField              label;
54      private BasicEditField          input;
55      private ButtonField             parseButton;
        .
        .
        .
```

and nowhere do I have a field (or method), *url*, in the class let alone at that line. I've tried refreshing, closing/opening the file, bouncing Eclipse, etc.

While this is a only a warning, I try to fix/eliminate all warnings in my code. At very least, I want to be convinced I know why I shouldn't care about each one I let pass.

I've spent a great deal of time looking for a solution to this problem without success. It would be nice to have a definitive answer and not, "just ignore it."

Thanks,

Russ Bateman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about Blackberry programming, but eliminating warnings is big deal for me. Does the warning move if you re-arrange the order of the fields? If you changed label to BasicEditField would you get two warnings? You need some kind of reality check to prove the warning goes with that file - for instance, deliberately put in a compile error after the location of the warning. I've een case where compilers were grabbing old versions of files (from other projects, etc). Good Luck!

Comment: I'm getting the impression that this error, which doesn't correspond to the line number, appears to come from an older version of the file as suggested since it is true that early on I did have a field named url. Ultimately, this went away and, after a few more iterations, it was replaced by another complaint.